# An app that helps determine lands in a Magic: The Gathering deck

Tags: rust

Good evening,  I'm new to Rust and would like some help refactoring this small app I made so that it's more efficient, even if it may be unnecessary.

Basically I'm trying to figure out better ways to do stuff, and if I could analyze how someone would do the same thing, but better, I think it could help me learn a bit more about the language.

I haven't got too far into the language yet, but I would like to nip any bad habits I might run into before they become a problem.

What this app basically does, is it asks for how many cards are in a Magic: The Gathering deck, and then a few questions about the cards, then determines how much and what types of lands you should have in the deck.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let deck_size = get_deck_size();
    let spells = get_spell_count(deck_size);
    let total_cmc = get_total_cmc();

    calculate_mana(deck_size, spells, total_cmc);

    fn get_deck_size() -> f32 {
        loop {
            let mut input = String::new();
            println!("How many cards are in your deck?");
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input)
                .expect("Failed to read input.");
            let input = input
                .trim()
                .parse::<f32>()
                .expect("Please enter a valid number.");

            if input >= 40.0 {
                break input;
            }

            println!("Your deck is too small, the minimum amount of cards in a deck is 40, please enter a new deck size.")
        }
    }

    fn get_spell_count(deck_size: f32) -> f32 {
        loop {
            let mut input = String::new();
            println!("How many spells are in your deck?");
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input)
                .expect("Failed to read input.");
            let input = input
                .trim()
                .parse::<f32>()
                .expect("Please enter a valid number.");

            if input <= deck_size {
                break input;
            }

            println!("You have more spells in your deck than the amount of cards in your deck, please enter a new number of spells.")
        }
    }

    fn get_total_cmc() -> f32 {
        loop {
            let mut input = String::new();
            println!("What's the total converted mana cost of all your spells?");
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input)
                .expect("Failed to read input.");
            let input = input
                .trim()
                .parse::<f32>()
                .expect("Please enter a valid number.");

            if input >= 0.0 {
                break input;
            }

            println!("Something is wrong here.")
        }
    }

    fn calculate_mana(deck_size: f32, spells: f32, total_cmc: f32) {
        let mut symbol_count = Vec::new();
        let total_lands = deck_size - spells;
        let colors = ["white", "blue", "green", "red", "black", "colorless"];

        println!("Now we need to get all the mana symbols throughout your deck (not just in the cmc, but in the cards abilities as well).");

        for i in colors.iter() {
            let mut input = String::new();
            println!("How many {} symbols are in the deck?", i);
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input)
                .expect("Failed to read input.");
            let color = (
                input
                    .trim()
                    .parse::<f32>()
                    .expect("Please enter a valid number."),
                i,
            );
            symbol_count.push(color);
        }

        println!("Your average CMC is: {}", total_cmc / deck_size);
        println!("You should have {} total land", total_lands);

        for i in symbol_count {
            if i.0 > 0.0 {
                let x = ((total_lands / spells) * i.0).round();
                println!("{} of those lands should be {}", x, i.1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question title is too generic, change it to a brief description of what your code is supposed to do please.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code passes `rustfmt` and `clippy` — good job!

Here's my suggestions.

## Organization

Move the functions out of `main`.  The local functions make `main`
unnecessarily long.  Having free functions instead clarifies the
semantics of the program, and reduces the indentation.

## Type usage

In my understanding, the number of cards contained in a deck is always
a nonnegative integer, so it is probably better to use `u32` instead
of `f32` to store the card counts.  `u32` can be losslessly converted
to `f64` when doing floating point arithmetic.

## Error handling

When the user input cannot be deciphered, the program panics with an
error message.  Failing to read a line is probably an irrecoverable
error, but for parse errors, a better alternative is to ask the user
to re-enter data, so that users don't have to repeat everything they
typed because of a typo.

## Deduplication

This pattern occurs many times:

```
let mut input = String::new();
println!("<prompt>");
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut input)
    .expect("Failed to read input.");
let input = input
    .trim()
    .parse::<f32>()
    .expect("Please enter a valid number.");
```

We can make a dedicated function:

```
fn input(prompt: &str) -> Result<u32, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    println!("{}", prompt);

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("cannot read input");
    input.trim().parse()
}
```

Now, the functions that ask for input can be simplified:

```
fn get_deck_size() -> u32 {
    loop {
        match input("How many cards are in your deck?") {
            Ok(deck_size) if deck_size >= 40 => return deck_size,
            Ok(_) => println!("The minimum number of cards in a deck is 40."),
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
        }
    }
}

fn get_spell_count(deck_size: u32) -> u32 {
    loop {
        match input("How many spells are in your deck?") {
            Ok(spell_count) if spell_count <= deck_size => return spell_count,
            Ok(_) => println!("You cannot have more spells than cards."),
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
        }
    }
}

fn get_total_cmc() -> u32 {
    loop {
        match input("What's the total converted mana cost of all your spells?") {
            Ok(total_cmc) => return total_cmc,
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `total_cmc >= 0` check can be elided.

## Calculation

Here's my version:

```
const COLORS: [&str; 6] = ["white", "blue", "green", "red", "black", "colorless"];

fn calculate_mana(deck_size: u32, spells: u32, total_cmc: u32) {
    let total_lands = deck_size - spells;

    println!("Now we need to get all the mana symbols throughout your deck (not just in the cmc, but in the cards abilities as well).");
    let symbol_counts = get_symbol_counts();

    println!(
        "Your average CMC is: {}",
        f64::from(total_cmc) / f64::from(deck_size)
    );
    println!("You should have {} total land", total_lands);

    // FIXME: rename to fit game nomenclature
    let land_percentage = f64::from(total_lands) / f64::from(spells);

    for (&symbol_count, &color) in symbol_counts.iter().zip(COLORS.iter()) {
        if symbol_count > 0 {
            // FIXME: rename to fit game nomenclature
            let land_count = land_percentage * f64::from(symbol_count);
            println!("{} of those lands should be {}", land_count, color);
        }
    }
}
```

Changes I made:

- rename `i` to `color`;
- rename `symbol_count` to `symbol_counts`, since it's a vector;
- use [`.copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied), so that the vector stores the colors directly,
  rather than references to elements within the local array;
- promotes `colors` to a global `const`;
- use a separate function to read the data;
- remove the `.0` and `.1`, and store colors only once;
- use [`Vec::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) to avoid unnecessary reallocations.

I also reported the result as a floating point number, since they may
be helpful for, say, probabilistic analysis.  This is purely
subjective.

## Result

Putting everything together:

```
use std::io;

const COLORS: [&str; 6] = ["white", "blue", "green", "red", "black", "colorless"];

fn main() {
    let deck_size = get_deck_size();
    let spells = get_spell_count(deck_size);
    let total_cmc = get_total_cmc();

    calculate_mana(deck_size, spells, total_cmc);
}

fn input(prompt: &str) -> Result<u32, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    println!("{}", prompt);

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("cannot read input");
    input.trim().parse()
}

fn get_deck_size() -> u32 {
    loop {
        match input("How many cards are in your deck?") {
            Ok(deck_size) if deck_size >= 40 => return deck_size,
            Ok(_) => println!("The minimum number of cards in a deck is 40."),
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
        }
    }
}

fn get_spell_count(deck_size: u32) -> u32 {
    loop {
        match input("How many spells are in your deck?") {
            Ok(spell_count) if spell_count <= deck_size => return spell_count,
            Ok(_) => println!("You cannot have more spells than cards."),
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
        }
    }
}

fn get_total_cmc() -> u32 {
    loop {
        match input("What's the total converted mana cost of all your spells?") {
            Ok(total_cmc) => return total_cmc,
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
        }
    }
}

fn get_symbol_counts() -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut symbol_counts = Vec::with_capacity(COLORS.len());

    for color in COLORS.iter().copied() {
        let symbol_count = loop {
            // FIXME: could be written more clearly
            print!("How many {} symbols are in the deck?", color);
            match input("") {
                Ok(symbol_count) => break symbol_count,
                Err(_) => println!("Invalid number."),
            }
        };
        symbol_counts.push(symbol_count);
    }

    symbol_counts
}

fn calculate_mana(deck_size: u32, spells: u32, total_cmc: u32) {
    let total_lands = deck_size - spells;

    println!("Now we need to get all the mana symbols throughout your deck (not just in the cmc, but in the cards abilities as well).");
    let symbol_counts = get_symbol_counts();

    println!(
        "Your average CMC is: {}",
        f64::from(total_cmc) / f64::from(deck_size)
    );
    println!("You should have {} total land", total_lands);

    // FIXME: rename to fit game nomenclature
    let land_percentage = f64::from(total_lands) / f64::from(spells);

    for (&symbol_count, &color) in symbol_counts.iter().zip(COLORS.iter()) {
        if symbol_count > 0 {
            // FIXME: rename to fit game nomenclature
            let land_count = land_percentage * f64::from(symbol_count);
            println!("{} of those lands should be {}", land_count, color);
        }
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03c0e56ceaa603916896532865368376))